# how to type cast a string into integer in C and store it in the integer array?

Tags: c

I want to know how to type cast a string into integer , and not use sprintf() in C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as a string data type in C.  But to your question, you can use **int atoi ( const char * str )** and remember to include **<stdlib.h>**

Comment: Keep in mind that atoi is pretty new in the C-world, C90 and C99. If you don't have sprintf for some reason, you're unlikely to atoi.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have strings but it does have char arrays (which we often call strings), such as:

```
char someChars[] = "12345";
```

You can convert (not the same as type cast) the contents of the character array to an int like this:

```
int result;
sscanf(someChars, "%d", &result);
```

Or using atoi:

```
int result = atoi( someChars );
```

Type casting is like taking a bottle of Coke and putting a Pepsi label on the bottle.

Type conversion is like pouring a bottle of Coke into an Pepsi can.  Maybe it will fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a char array/const char * into an integer in C, at least not in a way that gives you a sensible integer result[1]. The only exception is if you use it to convert a single char into an integer, which is basically just widening it if you look at the bit representation.

The only way you can do the proper conversion functions like `atoi` or `sscanf`.

[1] Yes, I know you can convert a pointer (const char *) into an integer, but that converts the value of the pointer and not the value of the data it points to.

Comment: You meant sscanf I think, not fscanf.